# How to prevent gap between uinavigationbar and view in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, uikit, uinavigationbar

We are currently having an issue with navigation bar sizing when using modal presentation in iOS 13.

In most cases this works fine as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

However, in a few screens we get this weird effect, with the navigation bar having a lower height and a weird "see-through" gap between it and the view. As seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Both of the view controllers have the same values set for their properties, are modally presented and have the same constrains on their subviews (0 spacing from the superview/margins/top layout guide).

This issue doesn't happen in iOS 12, even when built with the iOS 13 SDK. Is this a known issue in iOS 13 (beta 8), or is there something we should adjust in the code/storyboard?

Comment: never saw that, can you provide sample project?

Comment: @LeonLucardie Hi  ,maybe this should be solved after ios 13 stable version be released .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yeah. I will check this issue again after iOS 13/XCode GM builds have been released. Since it also happens in XCode Swift/ObjC projects (as can be seen in the test project) we can at least rule out any Xamarin related issues.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Unfortunately it seems the issue still occurs in the stable (GM) version of iOS 13 and XCode 11

Comment: @LeonLucardie Sad hearing that .Does it also happens in XCode Swift/ObjC projects ?

Comment: As stated (and seen in the test project) it also happens in XCode Swift/ObjC projects. So it seems it's not necessarily Xamarin related.

Since the original link expired I have reuploaded the test project over here: https://ufile.io/zusigvpl

Comment: @LeonLucardie Yeah , that's strang .Hoping that Apple can solve this problem in the near future.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {  
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)  
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {  
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()  
    }
}
```

We found this work around [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/378841#378841) and it worked for us.

Answer (score 19):

Like Rod's answer, but I found it only works if I put setNeetsLayout() in next main thread runLoop:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Workaround for iOS 13 modal gap below navigationbar
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case these answers don't work make sure to set the navigation bar type to "Standard".